# Spring/Java project hierarchy: Where to put none model POJO classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, software-design, dto

I have a `@Service class FooService` that queries some external API. In return, it gets some `FooResponse`. This `FooResponse` is being used to create the model object but it's not a model by itself.

The project has a typical Spring project hierarchy (i.e. service, model, controller, config, utils)

Where should `FooResponse` reside at? Is it a `dto`?

Would you go with `dto.foo.FooResponse.java`? Or maybe just `dto.FooResponse.java`?

Comment: This is just a matter of personal preference. There are no objective answers, only opinions.

Comment: @Michael, what's yours then?

Comment: Not important or relevant

Comment: Okay, is there a style-guide I can follow then?

Comment: I personally recommend against the "typical hierarchy" and instead suggest packaging by subject, such as `com.example.bigapp.feature.external.foo.FooResponse` (along with `FooService`, `FooMapper`, and whatever else).

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for off-site resources such as a style guide are off-topic, sorry.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, interesting. And typically, which other packages you have under `feature` other than `external`?

Comment: Depends entirely on what the application is. For an authentication system, I had `feature.{useraccount,password,twofactor.sms,twofactor.totp}`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you can define your architecture using [hexagonal architecture](https://herbertograca.com/2017/11/16/explicit-architecture-01-ddd-hexagonal-onion-clean-cqrs-how-i-put-it-all-together/) then you should define domain model called `Foo` in domain/application layer and FooService should return `Foo` domain model and `FooResponse` can be encapsulated in `FooServiceImpl`

Package Structure

```
com..application.model.Foo
com..application.service.FooService
com..infrastructure.service.impl.FooServiceIml
```

interface FooService

```
Foo getFoo(T someParameter)
```

Class `FooServiceImpl`

```
com..infrastructure.service.impl
public class FooserviceImpl {

public Foo getFoo(T someParameter) {
  // call external service
  // getFooResponse
  // Map FooResponse to Foo and return Foo
}
```

In hexagonal architecture application/domain layer does not depend on outer layer (presentation, persistence, infrastructure). The benefit of this architecture is that you can change infrastructure code without affecting business logic(for example `FooServiceImpl` can be changed to use gRpc instead of REST without any change in application logic)